# How to discard a branch after training a pytorch model

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, autoencoder

I am trying to implement a FCN in `pytorch` with the overall structure as below:

[image]

The code so far looks like below:

```py
class SNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SNet, self).__init__()
        
        self.enc_a = encoder(...)
        self.dec_a = decoder(...)
        
        self.enc_b = encoder(...)
        self.dec_b = decoder(...)
    
    def forward(self, x1, x2):
        x1 = self.enc_a(x1)
        x2 = self.enc_b(x2)
        x2 = self.dec_b(x2)
        x1 = self.dec_a(torch.cat((x1, x2), dim=-1)
        return x1, x2
```

In `keras` it is relatively easy to do this using the functional API. However, I could not find any concrete example / tutorial to do this in `pytorch`.

1. How can I discard the `dec_a` (decoder part of autoencoder branch) after training?
2. During joint training the `loss` will be sum (optionally weighted) of the `loss` from both the branch?

Comment: You can set `model.dec_a = nn.Identity()` so that it no longer does anything and just returns the input. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: > You can set model.dec_a = nn.Identity()
That will still perform unnecessary computation if I am not wrong?

Comment: It will replace `dec_a` with a do-nothing layer. So the computations performed by the original `dec_a` will no longer take place.

Comment: Can I not create a new model without `dec_a` and initialize the weights with corresponding block from the trained network?

Comment: You can. It amounts to the same thing. You can check out the source of `nn.Identity()` (https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/linear.html#Identity) if you're worried about overhead; it literally just returns the input without doing anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also define separate modes for your model for training and inference:

```
class SNet(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super(SNet, self).__init__()
    
    self.enc_a = encoder(...)
    self.dec_a = decoder(...)
    
    self.enc_b = encoder(...)
    self.dec_b = decoder(...)
    
    self.training = True

  def forward(self, x1, x2):
    if self.training:
        x1 = self.enc_a(x1)
        x2 = self.enc_b(x2)
        x2 = self.dec_b(x2)
        x1 = self.dec_a(torch.cat((x1, x2), dim=-1)
        return x1, x2
    else:
        x1 = self.enc_a(x1)
        x2 = self.enc_b(x2)
        x2 = self.dec_b(x2)
        return x2
```

These blocks are examples and may not do exactly what you want because I think there is a bit of ambiguity between how you define the training and inference operations in your block chart vs. your code, but in any case you get the idea of how you can use some modules only during training mode. Then you can just set this variable accordingly.

Comment: I understand your point. What I am looking for is:
```   else:
        x1 = self.enc_a(x1)
        x2 = self.enc_b(x2)
        x2 = self.dec_b(x2)
        x1 = self.dec_a(torch.cat((x1, x2), dim=-1)
        return x1
```